# Need information cURL command and replace cURL with RESTClient

Tags: curl, rest-client

I just started learning RESTClient with RUBY, And i have seen cURL as below. I would like to know what exactly it is doing and more about -u (which actual used to insert the user and password), -X and -H. It would be help full for me if we do the same using RESTClient

```
%x(curl -u #{USER}:#{PASSWORD} -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '#{pusers.to_json}' #{HOST}/view/users).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  -u is for Server user and password
  -X is used for GET Request
  -H is used to send header data to the server
  -d is for the data part
```

You can check **Options** section on this [page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Or simply on black console just type

```
curl --help
```

you will get the list of options that can be used in curl.

Comment: Thank you for the information that you gave is really helpful. And also can you please change the cURL to RESTCLIENT

Comment: No idea of rest-client. Anyways if found helpful dont forget to upvote.